# Search column in SQL database ignoring special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, search

Does anybody know if it's possible to do a %LIKE% search against a column in a SQL Server database but get it to ignore any special characters in the column?

So, for example if I have a column called "songs" and they contain the following...

---

Black Or White

No Sleep 'till Brooklyn

The Ship Song

Papa Don't Preach

---

If the user searches for "no sleey till brooklyn" then I would like it to return a match even though they forgot to include the apostrophe. I would also like it to return the 4th row if they search for "SOUL". I'm sure you get the idea....

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you return the 4th row if they search for "SOUL"?

Comment: I'm not sure. I wrote this 10 years ago, maybe I copied and pasted the wrong list? Maybe somebody edited the question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would look into using a Full Text Index and then you can use the power of FREETEXT and CONTAINS to do your search.

EDIT: I would still look into refining the Full Text Index searching, however, to follow on from another answer, this is an option using REPLACE.

```
SELECT
    Artist,
    Title
FROM
    Songs
WHERE
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Artist, '#',''), '*', ''), '"', '') LIKE '%Keywords%'
```

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.  This really sounds like the way to go, IMO.  In fact I'm facing a similar situation right now and I'm just about to switch to full-text searching.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason I am investigating the possibility of writing our own queries for this is that we currently use full-text indexing and the client doesn't like it because they say it returns too many irrelevant results!

Comment: @Jon, have you looked into this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You will have various characters to remove. Single quotes, double quotes, hyphens, dots, commas, etc.

You can use Regular expressions in your where clause and do a match on the clean value. [Read more about regex within SQL here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

As for the art where you want to return the 4th row for SOUL.. you will need a a data structure to tag songs and you will have to search on the tags for the match. I'm afraid we will need more details on your data structure for that.

Comment: I am terrible at using Regex's but may be able to find a regex on line which removes special characters. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just stumbled upon it and am also working with song titles and want to expand upon the accepted answer that uses `REPLACE`. You can create a list of the characters you want to ignore and create a simple function in any language to generate the quick'n'dirty never-ending `REPLACE` lines. For example, in Python:

```py
def sanitize(db_field):
    special_chars = ['•', '"', "\\'", '*', ',']
    sanitized = "REPLACE({}, '{}', '')".format(db_field, special_chars.pop(0))
    for s in special_chars:
       sanitized = "REPLACE({}, '{}', '')".format(sanitized, s)
    return sanitized
```

A call such as `sanitize("name")` will return

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '•', ''), '"', ''), '\'', ''), '*', ''), ',', '')
```

which can be used in your query. Just wrote this so hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [TRANSLATE, UPPER, and TRIM](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/44094/0/).

Comment: I just did a search for these functions but can't find any information.

Comment: The SQL Server equivalents are UPPER, LTRIM, RTRIM. There isn't a TRANSLATE function but you can use multiple REPLACE functions for each of your special characters.

Comment: So, can I use a REPLACE on a column name, like this....  SELECT Artist, Title FROM Songs WHERE Artist.REPLACE('#','').REPLACE('*','') LIKE '%Keywords%';