# Remove special character from begining and end of string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

sql server 2008

I have a data in a column something like

```
"Brake pad kit, disc brake"
/Brake disk (sold separately).
"The belt pulley, crankshaft"
 Fuel Pump
```

the special character are "",space,/

i want to remove any **special character or space** present in **begining** or **end** of the string.

is this possible to do in sql, not sure.
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289178/search-column-in-sql-database-ignoring-special-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using String functions

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200)= '"The belt pulley, crankshaft"' 

SELECT Reverse(CASE 
                 WHEN LEFT(Reverse(scd_str), 1) LIKE '[A-Z]' OR LEFT(Reverse(scd_str), 1) LIKE '[a-z]' THEN Reverse(scd_str) 
                 ELSE Substring(Reverse(scd_str), 2, Len(Reverse(scd_str))) 
               END) 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN LEFT(string, 1) LIKE '[A-Z]' OR LEFT(string, 1) LIKE '[a-z]' THEN string 
                 ELSE Substring(string, 2, Len(string)) 
               END AS Scd_Str 
        FROM   (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(@str)) AS string) A) B
```

**Result :** `The belt pulley, crankshaft`

Comment: will it also work for hidden character in string. please suggest

Comment: @RohiniMathur - What do you mean by hidden character ? any examples?