# How to query the word without '(single quote) and display the result with '(singe quote)?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search a word from the database with single quote like a word can't and if I search a word like cant without single quote, can't still be displayed.

```
    <?php
    // Attempt search query execution
    try{

        if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
            // create prepared statement
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name LIKE :term";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $term = '%' . $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
            // bind parameters to statement
            $stmt->bindParam(':term', $term);
            // execute the prepared statement
            $stmt->execute();
            //fetch the data if there is a name and else no matches found
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                    echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        }  
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    // Close statement
    unset($stmt);
    // Close connection
    unset($pdo);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all unwanted characters like this:

```
REPLACE(name, '#','')
```

In your case that would be:

```
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE REPLACE(name, '\'','') LIKE :term
```

If you want more special chars to be deleted you need to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '\'',''), '*', '') LIKE :term
```

Comment: Can you please echo the quoted string and see if thats the term you search? (`echo $pdo->quote($_REQUEST['term'])`)

Comment: I applied your code and even a single word displays No matches found.

Comment: So please read my comment again. Please echo the quoted string that we send to the database

Comment: I got this result %'can\'t'%.

Comment: Try with `$term = '%' . addslashes($_REQUEST['term']) . '%';` pdo prepared statements should take care of the escaping anyways

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. As far as I understand it, she wants to search for `cant` (without single quote) and get all rows that contain `can't` (with a single quote) as well.

Comment: @Marvin Fischer I already tried this one and got the same result. I'm trying to search the term can't without the ' like cant. Is there a solution on this one or I just leave it here?

Comment: Is that only for ' or all special characters? If its only ' you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289178/search-column-in-sql-database-ignoring-special-characters

Comment: Also is the ' in the database or the user string?

Comment: @MarvinFischer in the database.

Comment: Then try the link from 3 comments above

Comment: @MarvinFischer It works now, by the way can you explain the code? What if I want to ignore all special characters? Thanks.

Comment: It just replaces every ' with an empty string so `a'b''c` would just be replaced to `abc`, you need to make a new replace for every special char, ill edit it how to do it

Comment: @MarvinFischer I got a problem, now that I want to search with ' it shows no result but when I searching for without ' it shows. When I searching for the word cant it shows the word can't but when I search for the word can't it shows no result. What should I do?

Comment: You should also replace the ' characters in the search term