# SQL: Select from column ignoring certain characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I'm new to SQL. I've got a column of US city names and I'm creating an autosuggest that retrieves city names as the user types one in. I've got it like

```
SELECT city FROM cities WHERE city ILIKE $1 || '%' LIMIT 4
```

This works, but I'd like it to work for some edge cases that include non-alphabetic characters -- specifically, some city names contain periods (St. Louis, St. Paul), and a couple contain hyphens (Wilkes-Barre, Winston-Salem). I want it so that if the user types in "st l", it will know to suggest "St. Louis" (but I also want it to work if the user did include the period and types in "st. l").

Googling a little bit I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289178/search-column-in-sql-database-ignoring-special-characters), which seems to have the same issue as me. So I tried

```
SELECT city FROM cities WHERE REPLACE(city, '.', '') ILIKE $1 || '%' LIMIT 4
```

which seems like a logical solution (there are only two characters I want to ignore), but I find it doesn't retrieve anything. Is there anything I'm overlooking here that you can see? It feels like this should work. (It's worth noting that even if this SELECT did work the way I intend it, it would mean I could only search WITHOUT the period, which is not what I want either; I want it to retrieve "St. Louis" whether I type in "st l" OR "st. l").

Update: I feel silly... it turns out the problem was not with the SQL, which was working as intended; the issue was I was misunderstanding how MUI's Autocomplete works (I was successfully passing it the four city names retrieved from my Postgres db as options, but in the case of typing in "st lo" the Autocomplete does not see any of those options as matching the input and therefore doesn't display anything. The solution was I had to add a filterOptions to the autocomplete. MUI Autocomplete doesn't just display whatever is passed to it as options; it compares the input vs its options and gives you what matches.)

Comment: I think you need to do the replace on both city and $1

Comment: Maybe you want fulltext search?

Answer (score 1):

you're almost there. using REPLACE(city, '.', '') is correct for removing periods, but you're encountering a problem because it only matches the city when there's an exact match after removing the periods.

to make it work with partial matches, you can use the ILIKE operator on the modified string. but you'd also need to include the original city name in your search to ensure it works with and without periods like this

```
SELECT 
  city
FROM 
  cities
WHERE 
  REPLACE(city, '.', '') ILIKE REPLACE($1, '.', '') || '%'
   OR 
  city ILIKE $1 || '%'
LIMIT 
  4;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; the "OR" part is exactly what I was looking for to make it still work with the period, so that is good to know. Adding the REPLACE on the $1, however, doesn't seem to help in the way you suggested, but I've found that my original query ("SELECT city FROM cities WHERE REPLACE(city, '.', '') ILIKE $1 || '%' LIMIT 4") actually does get me St. Louis for "st l" when I run it in DBeaver, so clearly the issue has something to do with the Node API retrieving the results rather than the SQL. Thanks again for the OR part, though!